# C# Memory Access Violation

Tags: c#-2.0

This code works fine and can be called numerous times without any problems.
However, if the bitmap is resized (made bigger), I get an access violation.
This is not the case if the bimap is made smaller.

I can confirm that the BMPSize & BitmapBytes array size tally at all times.

Can anyone spread any light on this, please?

```
public void SetBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        UInt32 BMPSize = Convert.ToUInt32(bmp.Height * bmp.Width * 4);
        BMPSize += 0x36;

        if (!FileMappingCreated)
        {
            MemoryFileHandle = CreateFileMapping((IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0,
                PageProtection.ReadWrite, 0, BMPSize, SharedName);

            if (MemoryFileHandle != null)
            {
                SetNamedSecurityInfo(SharedName, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                    IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);


                ViewFile = MapViewOfFile(MemoryFileHandle, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);


                if (MemoryFileHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(MemoryFileHandle);
                }
                else
                {
                    FileMappingCreated = true;
                }
            }
        }

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();          

        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        byte[] BitmapBytes = stream.ToArray();

        // BMP SIZE Value 4bytes long see internet for DIB structure.
        byte[] DIBImageSize = null;
        int ImageSizeAddress = 0x22;

        DIBImageSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(BMPSize)); 

        // put DIBImageSize into array starting at address 0x22
        for (int i = 0; i < DIBImageSize.Length; i++)
        {
            BitmapBytes[ImageSizeAddress] = DIBImageSize[i];
            ImageSizeAddress++;
        }   

        // THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS  
       Marshal.Copy(BitmapBytes, 0, ViewFile, Convert.ToInt32(BMPSize));           

        BitmapBytes = null;
        DIBImageSize = null;
        FileMappingCreated = false;
    }
```

Many thanks to all.

PyroPaul

Answer (score 1):

As I know, the bitmap size is also limited by the capability of the display card.  We normally do not exceed any texture/ bitmap size larger than 1024 x 1024px. Some strange errors will occur if your bitmap is larger than this size.

How big is your Bitmap? Try to cut it into pieces to load it piece by piece.

Comment: Thanks for your very prompt reply. I've just resized the bmp from 355k to 467k and I get this violation. Anything below 355k will be fine. If on the first use, the bitmap is, say, 900k then as long as I don't resize above that, everything works fine. This is called numerous times by the app and only fails when resizing to a bigger bitmap from the initial size at start up

Answer (score 0):

> can confirm that the BMPSize &
>   BitmapBytes array size tally at all
>   times.

That's two out of three parameters.

Comment: I probably being a bit thick here. What 3rd Param are you referring to? If it's ViewFile, this will change each loop as I'm clearing ( to false) FileMappingCreated.

Comment: "If it's ViewFile, this will change each loop" - No it won't. Check handles in debugger.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that all the variables change with the resize and, therefore, so do the varibles in Marshal.Copy. It's not, in this case, keeping the original size and erroring as it writes past the size that was set on the first run.

Comment: This problem goes away if I do not use the same file name (SharedName) when resizing.

 CreateFileMapping((IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0,                PageProtection.ReadWrite, 0, BMPSize, SharedName);

Can anyone help?

Comment: "the problem goes away if I do not use the same file name..." is it related to the file in use issue? You cannot overwrite the file when it is in use. So write to a new file, then close the file and rename it back to old name then.